# Include category in keyword simple search

Tags: categories, search

Is it possible to include category names in keyword simple search?

```
{exp:search:simple_form channel="products" result_page="search/results" no_result_page="search/no_results" search_in="everywhere"}
<input type="text" name="keywords" class="fl"  id="search" value="Search..."/>
<input type="submit" value="" class="fl"/>
{/exp:search:simple_form}
```

If my category name was Hats, if you searched for Hats you would get the results from the Hats category

Comment: That is not possible using the native search module. You would need to use an addon to achieve that result. Solspace Super Search allows you to search category titles from the keyword field. This is the parameter you'd be interested in http://www.solspace.com/docs/super_search/search/#keyword_search_category_name

Comment: Low Search 2.4+ allows for searching selected categories by keyword as well: http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, you cannot do this, however, there is a simple extension you can use called Categories to Text to save your categories into text fields automatically. If you set those text fields to be searchable, then essentially you are searching the categories. And you can choose to hide those text fields on the backend by modifying the the publish layout.

Categories to Text: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/categories-to-text

Answer (score 3):

Simple Search won't natively search categories. Luckily there's an add-on called [Preparse](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/preparse/) from Solspace which will help make it work.

Low posted on his [blog](http://gotolow.com/blog/searching-non-field-data-with-low-search) about using Preparse to add categories into a searchable text field. Though the post refers to using Preparse with Low Search, it would function the same with Simple Search as well.